# Little problem with dropdown div on my navbar :(

Tags: html, css

I've created a little dopdown menu on a button which is on my navbar, and I have this problem. :(
[Picture of the problem :p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuDZv.png)

I searched and apparently I have to put absolute position, but it does not work either.
Here is the css of the dropdown:

```css
.navbarButton {
    color: white !important;
    font-family: "DINNextLTPro-Condensed" !important;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #555555;
    margin-top: 1.4em;
    padding-left: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.2em;
    text-align: right;
}
.navbarButton img {
    width: 1.4em;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
}
.playerProfilDropdownDiv {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.dopdownLink {
    color: white;
}
.dopdownLink:Hover {
    color: #e5e5e5;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
```

And it's html code:

```html
<div class="navbarRightContent ml-auto">
    <div class="navbarButton">
        <img src="<?=$steamprofile['avatar']?>"><a class="navbarLink" href="#" onclick="playerProfilDropdown()">Gordon Freeman</a>
        <div class="playerProfilDropdownDiv" id="playerProfilDropdownDiv">
            <a class="dopdownLink" href="index.php">Mon profil</a>
            <a class="dopdownLink" href="notifications.php">Notifications</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbarButton"><a class="navbarLink" href="settings.php"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></a></div>
</div>
```

Does someone have an idea ?
Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: set it to absolute and give it top and right values as well to position it correctly.

Comment: Thx a lot it's work better :) http://prntscr.com/se2zq5

Comment: Great. You could maybe accept my answer then :)

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, it is not recommended but it works. xD

```css
.playerProfilDropdownDiv {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #555555;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: -0.24em;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 0.15em;
}
```

[Clic here for preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsKke.png)